# Filtering sub-query results from main query T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, filter, subquery

I have tried

```
select title
from BOOKS B, AUTHOR A, LOANS U
where a.author_id = b.author_id
and not B.book_id = U.book_id
order by A.name
```

and

```
select title
from BOOKS B, AUTHOR A, LOANS U
where b.author_id = a.author_id
and not b.book_id in (select u.book_id from LOANS)
order by A.name, b.title
```

All I need would be results from my sub-query `select u.book_id from LOANS`

Basically the table LOANS contains a list of book_id 's which have been loaned from a library.

I need the book_id 's which haven't been loaned yet. Then need to have them sorted alphabetically by the author's name (thus the `order by A.name`)

Note: the table containing the books only contains the author_id. To get the author's name I need to compare that author_id to the id's in the table AUTHOR.

Anyone that can tell me what I'm doing wrong or - if I'm using a wrong method - what method to use instead?

Answer (score 1):

This will select the title of any books that have not been loaned out before.  We can check this by using the `NOT IN` statement to return any titles from BOOKS where the `book_id` isn't in the `LOANS` table:

```
SELECT b.title
FROM BOOKS b
INNER JOIN AUTHORS a ON a.author_id = b.author_id 
WHERE b.book_id NOT IN (
    SELECT book_id FROM LOANS
)
ORDER BY a.[Name]
```

You really should use ANSI join syntax instead of using `WHERE` statements.

Comment: Did you read my initial question? I have tried that, it didn't work. Also the way you did it I wouldn't be able to compare the author's name and it will result in MASSIVE amounts of books, while there are only 20 books...

PS: `and not b.book_id in (select u.book_id from LOANS)` is what I tried... Same as NOT IN

Comment: Yeah, I misread part of it, but you don't say how your query doesn't work, or why that would return a massive amount of books. In any case, edited my answer.  I'm also *really* not sure why you have the `author_id` in the `book` table, that design doesn't make any sense; you'd be better off with a list of authors containing the `book_id`.

Comment: True, and I'm using `where a.author_id = b.author id` instead of an `inner join` because it's for a class & I'll fail if I use stuff we haven't seen yet :P We're not at the INNER JOIN part - unfortunately.

Anyway, my problem was the query just using all the books + all possibilities due to me having used ´FROM LOANS U` in the main query aswell, which I shouldn't have.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: A book can have multiple authors.

Comment: @LajosArpad - No kidding.  Consider the Asp 3.0 Programmer's Reference; you wouldn't create 10 records for the book, one for each author, would you?  No, you would create one book entry, and 10 entries in the authors table.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Nope, because an Author can write many books. It's an m:n relationship and to cope with that you need to have a table for Authors, one for Books and another for the Author_Book relation.

Comment: Obviously they can.  I think we're arguing for the same thing... my point is, there is no `Author_Book` reference here. Putting the author_id in the `Book` table is bad design, which I think we can both agree on.

Comment: Well, then we agree to agree :)

Comment: ^ No worries, I didn't make the actual database :P It's a database made by the institute in order to get people to learn. I don't think they've considered good design :P

Answer (score 1):

Your queries join the `Loans` table, but then try to include results where there is no row in `Loans`.  The second query should work if you remove the join on `Loans`.  The first if you `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and check for `U.Book_Id is NULL`.

Incidentally, your subquery returns the qualified column `u.book_id`.  That isn't going to do what you expect in a select from `Loans`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it.
`FROM BOOKS B, AUTHOR A, LOANS U`
had to be `FROM BOOKS B, AUTHOR A`

My code which worked in the end:

```
select title
from BOOKS B, AUTHOR A
where b.author_id = a.author_id
and not b.book_id in (select u.book_id from LOANS U)
order by A.name
```

Comment: When I posted my answer your reply wasn't on there yet, Sorry man.
PS: If I didn't know your answer states the same as I answered, I wouldn't even realise it'ld work :D